# Word VBA - DocumentBeforeSave event?

Tags: vba, ms-word, savefiledialog, before-save

I am using the following VBA code to make a message box appear while saving the Word document,

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave _ 
 (ByVal Doc As Document, _ 
 SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
 Cancel As Boolean) 

 Dim intResponse As Integer 

 intResponse = MsgBox("Do you really want to " _ 
 & "save the document?", _ 
 vbYesNo) 

 If intResponse = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```

This code was written in a Class. But this does not work. Nothing happens when saving. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made it to work. Thanks to [AnalystCave.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890586/analystcave-com) for the help. This is what I did:

I create a new class named **EventClassModule** and copied the following code,

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave _
 (ByVal Doc As Document, _
 SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
 Cancel As Boolean)

 Dim intResponse As Integer

 intResponse = MsgBox("Do you really want to " _
 & "save the document?", _
 vbYesNo)

 If intResponse = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Then created a module named **mdlEventConnect** and copied the following code,

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule

Sub Register_Event_Handler()
 Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

After this on the **ThisDocument** copied the following code,

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    Register_Event_Handler
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Register_Event_Handler
End Sub
```

Saved the document and re-opened it. Now when I try to save the document it executed the **DocumentBeforeSave** event perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the `ThisDocument` section of your VBA Project in Word, not in a `Class` as it won't work there.

Here is an example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299.aspx

Answer (score 1):

With Word 2016 I found that a change was necessary

```
Set X.App = Word.Application
```

should be

```
Set X.appWord = Word.Application
```