# Word VBA - How to set the default save path?

Tags: vba, default, ms-word, savefiledialog

When the following code is executed it changes the directory of the save as dialog and shows the Save dialog,

```
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = "c:\newfolder\"
    .Show
End With
```

And the following code changes the default directory of the open dialog and shows the Open dialog,

```
  ChangeFileOpenDirectory "c:\newfolder\"
  Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath) = CurDir
  With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
     .Show
  End With
```

However, what I want to achieve is when the user clicks the Save or Save As icon on MS-Word it always needs to show the specific directory ("c:\newfolder\"). The above codes does not get executed when the Save or Save As icon clicked. I tried adding the code to the [DocumentBeforeSave event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054965/word-vba-documentbeforesave-event/31061282#31061282) but that shows the Save As dialog twice.

So, how to make MS-Word always so specific folder in Save dialog when the Save icon is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code to the DocumentBeforeSave event. It has ref parameter Cancel. After you display your dialog, you set

```
Cancel = True
```

This will cancel the following events so only your dialog is displayed.