# Disable "Save as" in Word 2013 using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I disable the Save As option in Word 2013?
I've tried all the following commands listed below, but the event is never trapped. Normal "Save" is always trapped, regardless of whether via the icon or the Word File command. Threads have mentioned changing the File command XML, but I do not have access to Visual Studio.

```
Sub Document_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub Document_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
 End Sub

Sub wd_DocumentBeforeSaveAs(ByVal Doc As Document, _
             SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeSave( _
        ByVal Doc As Document, _
        SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
        Cancel As Boolean)
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub FileSave()
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub FileSaveAs()
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub FileSaveAsWebPage()
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub FileSaveHtml()
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub SaveTemplate()
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub

Sub FileSaveFrameAs()
MsgBox ("Save Disallowed")
End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask why? What is your underlying problem? Crippling an entire Application in such a way must have a good reason...

Comment: The reason is that people are editing a master document, and I wish to control the exact location and name of the file after the document has been altered. A very reasonable practice. In the sample code I have tried every combination to see what works, and have included this in there to demonstrate the options I have tried.

Comment: Some of what you list doesn't even exist... What does exist has, for the most part, been made obsolete by the incorporation of "Save As" in the Backstage. Application.DocumentBeforeSave method should still work, but as you have it, it won't "skip" SaveAs because you don't set the parameter SaveAsUI to False. The main problem with the event is that, if more than one add-in is using it, another add-in could allow it to run. Most reliable is to include RibbonXML that hides the builtin Backstage "Save As" and defines your own version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer, yes, the DocumentBeforeSave command does work, but the trick is in knowing where it has to go.

Found the answer here....

[Word VBA - DocumentBeforeSave event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054965/word-vba-documentbeforesave-event)

The solution works a treat!