# How to catch event at catia v6 macro

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, catia

I am novice at catia v6 macro development. I have already develop some macro like traverse spec tree, update document id etc at c# and vba.

I need to know how to catch event while saving a document. Suppose I have to update some properties automatically while saving the document.

The code should be like this...

```
CATIA.ActiveDocument.BeforeSave += BeforeSaveMethod;
Private void BeforeSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: I did not found event BeforeSave or something like that. Please tell me how to find it or any other workaround.

Comment: See this answer: [EventClassModule to Intercept Word Application Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054965/word-vba-documentbeforesave-event/39551858)

Comment: @Stringly, This solution does not work for me. I am using Catia applicationn.